# Entity Framework property as subquery with lazy loading and custom CRUD for tree structure

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I need to create tree structure and decided to use Tree traversal. How could I set this up to have lazy loading for `Parent` and `Children` properties and also manage it's CRUD operations. I would like to end up with easy operation like:

```
grandparentCode = lightBlue.Parent.Parent.Code;
big.Parent = lightBlue.Children.Where(c => c.Code == "blue");
```

Some code, starting with (Mysql) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `Id`        int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `NodeLeft`  int(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  `NodeRight` int(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  `Code`      varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 

  CONSTRAINT `PK__ProductCategory` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

entity:

```
class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

get parent procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetProductCategoryParentByChildId
    (IN childId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT categories.*
    FROM
        (SELECT NodeLeft, NodeRight, NodeLevel FROM ProductCategory WHERE Id = childId) childCategory
        INNER JOIN ProductCategory categories ON
            categories.NodeLeft < childCategory.NodeLeft
            AND categories.NodeRight > childCategory.NodeRight
            AND categories.NodeLevel = (childCategory.NodeLevel - 1);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

node level:

```
CREATE VIEW ProductCategoryNodeLevel
AS
    SELECT
        categories.Id, COUNT(children.Id) AS NodeLevel
    FROM
        ProductCategory categories
        LEFT JOIN ProductCategory children ON
            children.NodeLeft < categories.Nodeleft
            AND children.NodeRight > categories.NodeRight
    GROUP BY categories.Id
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you seem to have a nested set hierarchy here. This means that `lightBlue.Children` will never work, because there are no foreign keys. I think the best option is to have some custom queries in service methods that produce a parent with child nodes.

Comment: Yes, it is nested structure. I do not have foreign keys for that but I hope to use custom SQL or LINQ for finding them for every entity. Something like `GetProductCategoryParentByChildId` draft of procedure, this way I could get parent eventually.

Comment: I don't know any ORM that has native nested set support, so you're on your own here. I think you are aware of Joe Celko's book on the topic? Or [this blog](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).